# How does change in magnitude of a point charge reflect change in its electric field at a particular point in space with respect to time?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

We know that electric charge of an object results in an electric field formed around it. We also know that varying the magnitude of a point charge does not instantly produce a change in the electric field produced all around it. So how long does it take for the electric field at a particular point in space to reflect a change in magnitude? What are the factors that it depends on?

Comment: Are you familiar with [the speed of light?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unphysical question. Charge conservation means that a point charge cannot suddenly change its charge, any more than the Sun can suddenly disappear (a popular but unphysical scenario raising a similar question about gravity).

In physically-possible scenarios involving a sudden change in a charge distribution at $t=0$, the change in the electric field propagates outward at the speed of light. Beyond radius $ct$, the field is still the old field. Within radius $ct$, the field is the new field. At radius $ct$, there is a “kink” in the field representing an electromagnetic pulse carrying energy, momentum, and angular momentum to infinity.

Comment: I'm sorry, I intended the change in charge magnitude to be hypothetical in order to address the question of how the change in field would be effected.

Comment: I added a second paragraph which addresses that.